# I wish to add members to a project using checkboxes (Firebase React)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, checkbox, collections, document

For a school project, I wish to be able to add members to a project. By clicking on their checkboxes on the page and creating the project with the selected checkboxes on, it would take the information of the members and insert them as an object in a table known as members :

tree:

Collection(membres)/user.uid/projects/projectID/membres[{memberID, member.name, member.email}]

Here's my full component to creating a project:

```
import { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { onSnapshot, collection, doc, addDoc, setDoc, arrayUnion } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../../config/firebase';
import { authContexte } from "../../Contexte/authContexte";
import Spinner from "../Spinner/Spinner";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const CreerProjets = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const ctx = useContext(authContexte);
    const [contact, setContact] = useState([]);
    const [client, setClient] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [newProjet, setNewProjet] = useState({
        description: '',
        nom: '',
        color: '#000000',
        membres: [],
        client: {}
    });
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

    //Pour recevoir la date actuel (jj/mm/aaaa)
    const current = new Date();
    const showTime = `${current.getDate()}/${current.getMonth() + 1}/${current.getFullYear()}`;

    // Pour reçevoir l'information des membres
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'membres', ctx.user.uid), (snapshot) => {
            // console.log(snapshot.data());
            setContact({
                ...snapshot.data(),
                id: snapshot.id
            })
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
        return unsub;
    }, []);

    // Pour reçevoir l'information des clients
    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db, 'clients'), (snapshot) => {
            setClient(snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                return {
                    ...doc.data(),
                    id: doc.id
                };
            }));
        });
        return unsub;
    }, []);

    const updateProjet = (texte, prop) => {
        setNewProjet(current => {
            return {
                ...current,
                [prop]: texte
            };
        });
    };

    const SubmitForm = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

      **  //ERROR IS HERE, THIS IS WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR AND I CANNOT GET ANYTHING ELSE BUT THE ID OF THE MEMBER**
        selected.map(id=>{
            return {
                id: id,
                nom: //Name of member with id here
            };
        });
        console.log(selected)


        const projetRef = collection(db, "membres", ctx.user.uid, "projets");

       const resp = await addDoc(projetRef, {
            nom: newProjet.nom,
            description: newProjet.description,
            color: newProjet.color,
            date: "Créé le "+showTime,
            membres: selected,
            clients: newProjet.client
        }, { merge: true });

        console.log(resp.id) // id du projet qui se crée
        console.log(resp)

        navigate('/projets');
    };

    const CheckMembres = async (e) => {
        const { checked, value } = e.currentTarget;
        setSelected(prev => checked ? [...prev, value] : prev.filter(val => val !== value));

    };



    return (
        <section>
            {isLoading ? <Spinner /> : (
                <form style={{ marginTop: 50 + 'px' }} noValidate onSubmit={(e) => SubmitForm(e)}>
                    <div className="">
                        {/* Couleur du Projet */}
                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                            <span className="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Couleur du projet</span>
                            <input type="color" onChange={(e) => updateProjet(e.target.value, 'color')} className="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" value={newProjet.color} />
                        </div>

                        {/* Titre du Projet */}
                        <div className="input-group mb-3">
                            <span className="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Nom du Projet</span>
                            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => updateProjet(e.target.value, 'nom')} className="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" value={newProjet.nom} />
                        </div>

                        {/* Description du Projet */}
                        <div className="mb-3">
                            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlTextarea1" className="form-label">Description du Projet</label>
                            <textarea onChange={(e) => updateProjet(e.target.value, 'description')} className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" value={newProjet.description}></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="formDroit">

                        {/* Pour les membres */}

                        <div className="checkboxMembres">
                        <p>Contacts:</p>
                       {contact.contacts.map((membre)=>(
                        <div className="form-check form-switch" key={membre.nom + membre.email}>
                            <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" onChange={(e)=>CheckMembres(e)} value={membre.id} checked={selected.some(val => val === membre.id)}/>
                            <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault">{membre.nom}</label>
                        </div>  
                       ))}
                    </div>

                        {/* Pour les clients */}

                        {/* <div className="selectClient">
                        <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Ajouter un Client</label>
                        <select className="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
                            <option defaultValue>Pas de Client</option>
                            <option value="1">Client1</option>
                            <option value="1">Client2</option>
                            <option value="1">Client3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div> */}

                    </div>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary btnProjet" type="submit">Créer votre projet!</button>
                </form>)}
        </section>
    );
};
export default CreerProjets;
```

Answer (score 1):

After much suffering, I managed to get it! For anyone who wants the answer here it is:

```
const SubmitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const Membre = contact.contacts.filter((user)=>selected.includes(user.id));

    const projetRef = collection(db, "membres", ctx.user.uid, "projets");

    const Projet = await addDoc(projetRef, {
        nom: newProjet.nom,
        description: newProjet.description,
        color: newProjet.color,
        date: "Créé le "+showTime,
        membres: Membre,
        clients: newProjet.client
    }, { merge: true });

    console.log(Projet.id) // id du projet qui se crée

    console.log(Membre);
    

    navigate('/projets');
};
```